# same or similar search word with field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

I am using arcgis 10.1
I have two tables A and B need to find attributes of table B data are on the table A
I'm doing a join between table A and B now I want to use the field calculator via a script  to compare field "name" field of table A and table name B
I need help on how to make this script

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking for duplicate row values between fields, an [UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) is what you want.  Attached is a simple script to accomplish this goal.  The assumptions here are that you have three fields: FIELD1 (`row[0]`) and FIELD2 (`row[1]`) are being compared and the results are recorded in FIELD3 (`row[2]`), where "1" = duplicate and "0" = unique.

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\your\fc'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["FIELD1", "FIELD2", "FIELD3"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == row[1]:
            row[2] = 1
        else:
            row[2] = 0
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: you know how to configure this script 

for functions modelbuilder 

and that "fc = R'c: \ path \ to \ your \ fc '

imput be a "shp"